# How to get N modulo Q from N modulo P, where P & Q are coprimes and P > Q?

Tags: math, modulo

I wonder if there is some method to get correct remainder of N after dividing with Q (or modulo Q) from the given remainder of N after dividing with P(or modulo P).
 In other words you have N%P, P and Q. You have to find out N%Q, given that gcd(P,Q) = 1.

Example.  Suppose P = 19 and Q = 15. Now, for N =100, we can compute N%P = (100 % 19) = 5
and N % Q = (100 % 15) = 10. But, suppose if you are not given 100, then how can you get N % Q = 10 from the given P(=19) and remainder (N % P) = 5.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: This question might be about Public Key Cryptography in Internet Security

Answer (score 3):

You can not get a definite answer because there are many possible N which will give the specified remainder. Let's consider your example.  We know that N % P = N % 19 = 5. The possible values of N are: 24 (19+5), 43 (19+19+5), 62, (19+19+19+5), 81, 100, 119... Taking this into account the possible remainders of N % Q = N % 15 are 9,13,2,6,10,14... and 10 is only one of possible solutions (more precisely there are Q possible remainders (solutions) of dividing by Q).